# Auto import components Nuxtjs not working

Tags: laravel, vue.js, components, nuxt.js

I'm confused why it didn't work on my vue file when Im trying to auto import components in my view, the documentation says [link](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/components/) you just need to set the components into `true` inside `nuxt.config.js` file, I tried but it doesn't work, do I properly import the custom vue?

this is my **directory**

```
Components
    >Timeline.vue
    >TimelineItem.vue
```

**This will works fine** but I want to automate and remove the `import`from script

```html
<template id="timeline-template">
  <ul class="timeline">
    <li
      is="TimelineItem"
      v-for="(item, index) in items"
      :key="index"
      :item="item"
    ></li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
import TimelineItem from './TimelineItem.vue'
export default {
  components: { TimelineItem },
  props: ['items'],
}
</script>
```

So I just updated my script like this I just removed the import file since I want to automate it

```html
<script>
export default {}
</script>
```

Then in my `nuxt.config.js` I set the component into `true`

```js
components: true,
```

This is my **TimelineItem.vue**

```html
<template id="timeline-item-template">
  <li class="timeline-item">
    <div class="timeline-badge" :class="item.icon_status">
      <i :class="item.icon_class"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="timeline-panel">
      <div class="timeline-heading">
        <h4 class="timeline-title">{{ item.title }}</h4>
        <div class="timeline-panel-controls">
          <div class="controls">
            <a
              v-for="(control, index) in item.controls"
              :key="index"
              :control="control"
            >
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="timestamp">
            <small class="text-muted">{{ item.created }}</small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="timeline-body">{{ item.body }}</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['item'],
}
</script>
```

#### Updated

I tried using `<TimelineItem/>` instead using `is="TimelineItem` but it doesn't work

```html
<template id="timeline-template">
  <ul class="timeline">
    <TimelineItem v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index" :item="item" />
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['items'],
}
</script>
```

Comment: have you tried using the components with their names as the tag name?
`<TimelineItem/>`
instead of
`<li is="TimelineItem"/>`

Comment: @Sherif Hassan [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjJ4E.png) This is what I've tried on this image, but it seems it doesn't recognize, did I implement it properly?

Comment: Do you have a public Github or a [repro] of the issue? Hard to say why the suggested solution above does not work. It should work well. Maybe a bug or something done on your side, not sure.

Comment: try naming the directory `components` all in lowercase

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of your folders? Or better, a [repro] or a public github repo?

Comment: @SherifHassan I tried also that but I think the problem is on how should I call the `<TimelineItem>`  and because currently I used `is="TimelineItem"` inside `<li>` I have added code above under updated

Comment: First off, try to at least have a working `TimelineItem` + `Timeline` combo, then go into more complex cases.

Comment: @kissu [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W14nc.png)  Yes when I use ` is="TimelineItem` It works,  but when I tried to remove `import` and use `<TimelineItem>` it did not work, the timeline did not display, I have SS of my folder in my comment, need help

Comment: Your structure is `components/template/Timeline.vue` so?

Comment: @kissu It works  now the problem is I forgot to import the `TimelineItem` inside componets.js Thank you so much~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's issue was fixed by importing `TimelineItem` inside of `components.js`!

Everything is working fine, as expected.